# Pressing tab in blade template wraps text in xml tags

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-blade

I'm having a new issue since moving to PhpStorm 8.0.3 Whenever I am in a `*.blade.php`.

Whenever I type some text and hit tab it wraps it as a xml element. I tried to disable all the the live templates, but the issue still occurs.

This is pretty annoying as I can't tab through live templates I've created.

```
asd \t
<asd></asd>
```

Does anyone know of another settings I may have over looked?

Comment: That's an **Emmet** in action. You can disable it (will affect other HTML/XML files as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's **Emmet** in action.

You can disable it if so desired, but keep in mind that this will affect other languages/formats as well (e.g. HTML/XML files).

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Emmet | Enable XML Emmet**